# How to use user defined aggregate in EF 6.1?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlclr

I have EF database first project and I would like to build query that will be accessing database using custom aggregate like this below for string concatenation

http://angusmiller.co.za/2010/01/28/clr-user-defined-aggregates-concatenate-strings-with-separator/

Is there any way to do this?